# Remove special characters but allow spaces

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following which removes special characters from being entered into a input

```
$('input').on('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Is there any way I can add spaces to this, and limit it to only 8 characters being entered?

Thanks

Comment: Add a space to your regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`?

Comment: When you limit it to 8 characters (which should be a straightforward string length calculation - ten seconds on Google will tell you how to do that), make sure you don't interfere with the backspace key press, or your form will be *very* frustrating.

Comment: Add a `maxlength` attribute to your input HTML.

Comment: Add `\s+` to the pattern to pick up one or more spaces: `[a-zA-Z0-9\s+]`

Comment: Note: 1. Don't use `new RegExp` if nothing in the pattern is variable, use a regular expression literal. 2. FWIW, modern browsers have `event.key`, which is the character. 3. Looking at the regex, what do **you** think you need to do to allow spaces? 4. What did your research turn up about limiting an input to eight characters?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments.  I have researched how to achieve this, my struggle is getting it into the current pattern.  Can I just place it anywhere?

Comment: ` var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");` seemed to work for spaces, didnt like `\s`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

[`^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/jtCk3B/1/)

Add a whitespace with `\s`

- Match the beginning of the string `^`
- Your characters including a whitespace `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]`
- Match the end of the string `$`